# Fetching pid and using it for kill

Tags: linux, bash

I have a batch file in linux (which I will execute externally from within my lazarus application). What it should do is read a process PID, store it in a variable, and use that variable to execute the "kill" command.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
PID=`pidof myProcess`
kill $PID
```

However, the kill command fails with a ": arguments must be process or job IDs" error.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Normally you get that error when the kill command is malformed. Can you post the actual kill line from your bash script here?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using. I copied/pasted my batch file content.

Comment: Interesting. I'm able to get that to work on a number of linux/mac machines. I even made a "myProcess" process to test it. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: One more silly question: have you verified that `pidof myProcess` works on the machine and user that calls the script? Some distributions don't ship with `pidof`. If that's not it, I'll leave you alone and let someone else jump in. :)

Comment: I can get the process pid using pidof (I added a echo $PID on my batch, just to test this) and it echoes the correct pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `pkill` directly would better suit your needs.

`pkill myProcess`

More info on pkill here: https://www.lifewire.com/list-and-kill-processes-using-the-pgrep-and-pkill-4065112